# Launch failed no binaries - gcc with eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, compiler-construction

I've just downloaded eclipse IDE for C/C++. Included `C:\MinGW\include` for headers and `C:\MinGW\lib` for librares but yet the build and run fails with error `"Launch failed no binaries"` what else i'm missing?

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Test ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -IC:\MinGW\include -IC:\MinGW\bin -IC:\MinGW -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -oTest.o ..\Test.cpp
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 112 ms.
```

Comment: I've decided to dump the IDE and find another!

Comment: Eclipse CDT's not the easiest, but the most powerful IDE available for free. Don't get disencouraged so fast.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows 64:
Project / Properties / C/C++ Build / Settings /Binary parsers: turn on "PE Windows Parser"

Answer (score 2):

Please check that C:\MinGW\bin is in your PATH.
If you open cmd and type g++ - there should be no messages that g++ can not be found.